# using numpy find common rows from one 2d array in another 2d array in any order

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numbers

I am trying to find the best option to maintain an index list of points using a point cache(ps0).  To do this I want to efficiently find all existing points from one 2d array(ps1) in another 2d cache array(ps0).  The cache array(ps0) doesn't have to be an numpy ndarray, but it's convenient if it is.  Ultimately I would also maintain an index list (ps_indexes) for the points.  The goal is to have functionality of ps_get_existing() you see in the code example.  Thank you for your help.  Yes, i'd like to use numpy's methods as much as possible since it's there.  The function ps_get_existing() returns indexes for all the points in one array(ps0) that that exist in the other(ps1), or None values for indexes that do not exist.

```
 import numpy as np

 >>> ps0 = np.ndarray(shape=(1000,2), dtype=np.float64)    # the point cache
 >>> ps0_length = 10
 >>> ps0[:ps0_length] = [    # point cache
        [-0.48505498,  0.12574257],
        [ 0.00761904, -0.5       ],
        [-0.09404923, -0.79025632],
        [-0.40395326,  0.48217822],
        [-0.32285154,  0.83861386],
        [-0.08257821,  1.33960396],
        [ 0.00761904,  1.41683168],
        [ 0.00761904,  1.41683168],
        [ 0.00761904,  1.41683168],
        [ 0.09781628,  1.33960396]]
 >>> ps1 = np.array([    # new point array
        [-0.26255921, -0.82617311],
        [ 0.00761904, -0.5       ],
        [-0.40395326,  0.48217822],
        [-0.37366057, -0.56056108],
        [-0.17125953,  1.14356436],
        [-0.48476193, -0.29494906],
        [-0.09404923, -0.79025632],
        [-0.25994085,  0.94752475],
        [-0.32285154,  0.83861386],
        [-0.48505498,  0.12574257]], dtype=np.float64)
 >>> indexes = ps_get_existing(ps0[:ps0_length], ps1) ### this is the functionality I am looking for!
 >>> indexes
 [None, 1, 3, None, None, None, 2, None, 4, 0]
 >>> for i in range(len(ps1)):
 ...   if indexes[i] is None:
 ...     indexes[i] = ps0_length
 ...     ps0[ps0_length] = ps1[i]
 ...     ps0_length += 1
 ... 
 >>> indexes
 [10, 1, 3, 11, 12, 13, 2, 14, 4, 0]
```